# Struggling to turn JSON data into Django model object instances

Tags: json, django, django-models

I'm trying to take a list of JSON objects, turn them into Python dicts, then populate the Concert model with an object for each of the Python dicts.

```
import json
from models import Concert
with open('output.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for concert in data:
    Concert.objects.create(**concert)
```

I'm getting an error message I haven't seen before:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Is this something that can be easily addressed? There is a foreign key in my model that corresponds to one of the key-value pairs in the JSON objects; is that relevant to this error?

Comment: How do you exeute this? Just some file somewhere? Typically you use a custom command for this, so that Django is first loaded. The problem is probably that by running the file, you do not load the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common error, if you **write an independent** python file and execute it.

## Defining a *custom command*

Although you *can* make sure the Django framework is properly loaded, usually the idea is that you define a [**custom command** [doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).

So in your file structure, if `app` is the application where your `Concert` is located, you can construct directories and files (here listed in boldface):

```
someapp/
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            load_concerts.py
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
```

Where the `__init__.py` files are empty. Then your `load_concerts.py` can look like:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import json
from app.models import Concert

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Load JSON concert data'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('concert_file', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with open(options['concert_file']) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        for concert in data:
            Concert.objects.create(**concert)
```

You can the execute the command with:

```
$ manage.py load_concerts output.json --settings=my_settings
```

So just like you run the server (well you can see this as a builtin command), you can thus add specific commands).

By defining the filename as a parameter, we can easily load any `.json` file we want.

## An *independent* Python program

You *can* define a loose Python file. In that case you need to load the settings, with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from projectroot import settings as projectsettings
settings.configure(projectsettings)

import django
django.setup()

import json
from app.models import Concert

with open('output.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for concert in data:
    Concert.objects.create(**concert)
```

Then you can set the `PYTHONPATH` to the project root, and thus load the specific settings, but I think this will probably result in more pain that to define a command you can easily reuse.

Comment: This is a really fantastic and thorough explanation and I greatly appreciate the time you took to draft it. I'm getting an ImportError: No module named management.commands.load_concerts. Most of my googling leads me to believe this is a problem with my __init__.py file missing or being named wrong, but I have checked and double-checked this question. Could it be anything else?

Comment: Of course! I edited my response with an error I'm getting after you submitted your reply. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: @Danny: argh, you probably should add an `__init__.py` file at the management level as well, sorry, will edit.

Comment: Ah, perfect. No need to be sorry at all. I appreciate your time. Now I'm getting an IOError: No such file or directory: 'output.json'. The file is in the same directory as the load_concerts.py file. I'm guessing I need to poke around in the settings to load from here? Or maybe I can put these files elsewhere?

Comment: Ah, then the path should be something like `someapp/management/commands/output.json` (with `someapp` the name of the app). The paths are relative to the location where you call the script from.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out. I'm now running into a new issue with foreign keys, but I'm going to mark this is as solved and open a new question. Hope to see you over there. :)

Comment: @Danny: well the foreign keys are probably due to the fact that your JSON cascades further in some other models, that first have to be constructed. So `.objects.create(**row)` can not (at least not straightforward) create such object.

Comment: Very helpful and detailed answer. Thumbs up!